# Django - populate a MultipleChoiceField via request.user.somechoice_set.all()

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Is there a more efficient, or cleaner way to do the following?

```
class SpamForm(ModelForm):
    some_choices = fields.MultipleChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SpamForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['some_choices'].choices = [[choice.pk, choice.description] for choice in self.instance.user.somechoice_set.all()]

    class Meta:
        model = Spam
```

This is to populate the new form with choices that pertain to the current `request.user` (which is set on the instance that's passed into the form). Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` in the form and set its `queryset` in `__init__()`.

Comment: the problem is that `ModelChoiceField` doesn't use a `multiple=multiple` select element, right?